# Declare object where one key is variable

Tags: javascript, object, variable-declaration

To declare an object where one of the keys is variable, you can do the following:

```
var obj={};
obj[variable]="foo";
```

Is they a more concise syntax ?

Comment: No, this is a good as it can get, unless you use a helper function.

Comment: Someone's gotta do it: `eval('var obj ={' + variable + ':"foo"}')`. Not posting it as an answer though…

Comment: @RobG I wouldn't call this more concise, just less readable... :)